# Prefixing JSON in MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

Tags: json, angularjs, spring-mvc, jackson

I've using Spring/AngularJS and to prevent JSON vulnerability, I'm trying to prefix all JSON array responses with ")]}',\n" - see [reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

I was able to prefix by

```
     <mvc:annotation-driven>
     <mvc:message-converters>
     <bean id="mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" >
     <property name="jsonPrefix" value=")]}',\n" />
     </bean>
     </mvc:message-converters>
     </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

But the problem is it's prefixing all JSON responses with ")]}',\n" and I only need to prefix the JSON arrays. Is there a way I could only set the prefix for JSON array responses? Thanks.

Comment: Why would it matter. The documentation states Angular will strip out the prefix. And no, the prefix is written for all responses.

Comment: Hit with another issue: AngularJS is not stripping out the prefix. Any thoughts?

Comment: How are you handling the request and response in your angular app?

Comment: I posted a separate question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250753/angularjs-http-not-stripping-off-prefix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring issues with configuration of JSON Prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32327638/spring-issues-with-configuration-of-json-prefix)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of having a prefix which basically makes your response invalid JSON consider returning a object instead of an array. This will mitigate the attack vector as well.

```
{d: [1,2,3,4]}
```

Comment: This would still be vulnerable because the contents would still be parsed into an array which would be readable by the attacker. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/

Comment: @Chic. Test it for yourself and override Array with `Array = function () { console.log(arguments); }` and JSON.parse the JSON in my answer

Comment: my mistake. I believe your answer should be sufficient. Blocked from un-downvote though.