# angularJS $http not stripping off prefix

Tags: angularjs

As per this [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), AngularJS will strip off the prefix `)]}',\n` in the JSON responses. I am sending my JSON responses with the prefix in my JSON responses but AngularJS is not stripping off the prefix and interpreting the results. Any idea? Thanks.

I sent the responses back from Spring as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249113/prefixing-json-in-mappingjackson2httpmessageconverter/25249477#25249477). And it's sending JSON response with the prefix `)]}',\n`. In AngularJS, I need to retrieve the values:

```
var Retrieve = $resource('app/', {..});
```

and in the success call back function:

```
var successQuestions = function (q) {
    $rootScope.q1 = q.question1;
};
```

I am expecting q JSON to be properly interpreted by AngularJS as a JSON but it is not.

Comment: can you bring example ? and show us what you do and what you expecting

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and noticed that the xhr object thought the response was null. The problem for me was that I had `responseType: 'json'` on the config of the request, so xhr was dropping the response before it ever got back to Angular since the response was not valid json.

Removing `responseType: 'json'` from the $http (or $resource in your case) request config fixed it for me.