# AngularJS JSON vulnerability protection not stripped

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, security, xss

I have an angular app communicating with an Api where I prefix JSON responses only consisting of an array with `)]}',` as the [angular's official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#json-vulnerability-protection) recommends to do.

The problem is, my browser seems to try to decode the response before angular does.

I've gone step by step in the debugger, and right after the `xhr.onload` callback is fired, the response is already **null**.

The code I'm talking about is this one :

```javascript
// From angular.js(1.5.9):12122
xhr.onload = function requestLoaded() {
        var statusText = xhr.statusText || '';

        // responseText is the old-school way of retrieving response (supported by IE9)
        // response/responseType properties were introduced in XHR Level2 spec (supported by IE10)
        var response = ('response' in xhr) ? xhr.response : xhr.responseText;

        // normalize IE9 bug (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1450)
        var status = xhr.status === 1223 ? 204 : xhr.status;

        // fix status code when it is 0 (0 status is undocumented).
        // Occurs when accessing file resources or on Android 4.1 stock browser
        // while retrieving files from application cache.
        if (status === 0) {
          status = response ? 200 : urlResolve(url).protocol === 'file' ? 404 : 0;
        }

        completeRequest(callback,
            status,
            response,
            xhr.getAllResponseHeaders(),
            statusText);
      };
}
```

`xhr.response` is null before angular does anything (I think).

Angular try to strip the prefix with this code :

```js
function defaultHttpResponseTransform(data, headers) {
  if (isString(data)) {
    // Strip json vulnerability protection prefix and trim whitespace
    var tempData = data.replace(JSON_PROTECTION_PREFIX, '').trim();

    if (tempData) {
      var contentType = headers('Content-Type');
      if ((contentType && (contentType.indexOf(APPLICATION_JSON) === 0)) || isJsonLike(tempData)) {
        data = fromJson(tempData);
      }
    }
  }

  return data;
}
```

But the data is never a string at this point, the browser has already tried to decode it (and failed).

The output of the Api looks like the following :

```
)]}',
[{"name": "A"},{"name": "B"}]
```

If I remove the prefix, it works normally. I've tried with :
 - Opera 45.0
 - Firefox 46
 - Chrome 58

They all behave similarly, so I may be missing something.

The response headers contain the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.11.5
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
[...]
Content-Length: 1793
```

Any idea ?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Why is your xhr.response null ? is your api returning a null response?

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25334223/1915893

Comment: Yes It's working.. I've failed to find this question when I was searching.. Anyway, can you please post an answer so I can accept it ? It will increase the chances for other people with the same problem to find the answer. Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Sure thing. Glad it worked. Just wish we could give credit to the original author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by Jeff Sheets in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25334223/1915893), your request configuration object may contain `responseType: 'json'`. This can cause the object to be dropped by the browser's underlying XMLHttpRequest implementation, which specifies this property before it is passed back to the application.

Removing the `responseType` property, or setting it to text should resolve the issue.

[`responseType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType) is documented on MDN where it is stated that

> Setting the value of responseType to "document" is ignored if done in a  Worker environment. When setting responseType to a particular value, the author should make sure that the server is actually sending a response compatible to that format. **If the server returns data that is not compatible to the responseType that was set, the value of response will be null.** Also, setting responseType for synchronous requests will throw an InvalidAccessError exception.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: I wonder if using `$http` instead of a hand rolled xhr would do this for you. There are reasons Angular wrapped certain browser functionality.

Comment: I believe the OP is using `$http`.

Comment: Ah, I see. His xhr.onload is $http's onload, not OP's own onload. My mistake.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same thing at first, but he is indicated the relevant lines of the AngularJS source code.